# Accessing class name inside nested tags with scrapy

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, scrapy

I have this following document

```
    <p class="contact-info " onclick="_ct('clntphn', 'lspg');">
    <i class="res_contactic resultimg"></i>
    <span>
        <a>
            <b>
                <span class="mobilesv icon-dc"></span>
                <span class="mobilesv icon-fe"></span>
                <span class="mobilesv icon-ji"></span>
                <span class="mobilesv icon-yz"></span>
                <span class="mobilesv icon-hg"></span>
                <span class="mobilesv icon-ba"></span>
                <span class="mobilesv icon-ji"></span>
                <span class="mobilesv icon-yz"></span>
                <span class="mobilesv icon-rq"></span>
                <span class="mobilesv icon-wx"></span>
                <span class="mobilesv icon-ts"></span>
                <span class="mobilesv icon-rq"></span>
                <span class="mobilesv icon-vu"></span>
                <span class="mobilesv icon-ji"></span>
                <span class="mobilesv icon-vu"></span>
                <span class="mobilesv icon-po"></span>
            </b>
        </a>
    </span>
</p>
```

I have a python dictionary which maps span class names to digits. For example:

```
    [icon-dc:+,
     icon-fe:9
    ]
```

1. How do I access the classnames in these nested tags using scrapy and get the contact info?

Answer (score 0):

try : `response.css(span span::attr(class)).extract()`
This will return list of span's class as `['mobilesv icon-dc', 'mobilesv icon-fe', ...]`
Iterate over list, split on `space` get the second attrib and find the content from your dict.

Hope this is what you are asking, otherwise let me know.

Thanks.